# Unconsumed column names sqlalchemy python

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am facing the following error using SQLAlchemy: `Unconsumed column names: company`

I want to insert data for 1 specific column, and not all columns in the table: `INSERT INTO customers (company) VALUES ('sample name');`

My code:

```
engine.execute(table('customers').insert().values({'company': 'sample name'}))
```

Create Table:

```
'CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `company` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `company_UNIQUE` (`company`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=63 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8'
```

Comment: Are you sure you have such a column in your table?

Comment: @GProst 100% sure

Comment: even testing the statement before executing throws the same error:

print(table('customers').insert().values({'company': 'sample'}))

Comment: Are you sure you connect to the same DB? Can you execute some other query to get some records for example?

Comment: yes, this entire design is based on a flask api application that I'm building. I have plenty of other statements running fine including updates, selects, deletes.@GProst

Comment: If I run print(table('customers').insert().values({})), I can see the insert statement of course with no columns or values. This just isn't adding up to me

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After hours of frustration, I was able to test a way that I think works for my use case. As we know, you can insert to specific columns, or all columns in a table. In my use case, I dynamically need to insert to the customers table, depending on what columns a user has permissions to insert to.

I found that I needed to define all columns in the `table()` method of sqlalchemy, but I can pass in whatever columns and values that I need dynamically to the `values()` method.

**Final code:**

```
engine.execute(table('customers', column('company'), column('first_name'), column('last_name'), column('email'), column('phone')).insert().values({'company': 'sample name'}))
```

Answer (score 6):

The original solution works great, however I'd like to add another approach that will allow working with tables dynamically, without specifying all of their columns. This can be useful when working with multiple tables.

We can use the `Table` class from `sqlalchemy.schema` and provide our `engine` to its `autoload_with` parameter, which will reflect the schema and populate the columns for us.

Then, we can work just like we in the OP's answer.

```py
from sqlalchemy.schema import Table, MetaData

my_table_name = 'customers'  # Could be passed as an argument as well :)
table = Table(my_table_name, MetaData(), autoload_with=engine)

engine.execute(my_table.insert({'company': 'sample name'}))
```